# Swift struct compiler error when declaring a private var

Tags: swift, struct, xcode12

I have a very simple `struct` which works as expected:

```
struct Obligation {
    
    var date = Date()
}

let snapshotEntry = Obligation(date: Date())
```

however if I add a private var to this struct, I get a compile error on the line I create an instance of my struct saying `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`:

```
struct Obligation {
    
    var date = Date()
    
    private var blank:Bool = false
}

let snapshotEntry = Obligation(date: Date())
```

[image]

If I remove the `private` from the new `blank` var it compiles fine.
Am I overlooking something simple here? Can a `struct` not have a private var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Access Control](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3) documentation clearly states:

> The default memberwise initializer for a structure type is considered
> private if any of the structure’s stored properties are private.
> Likewise, if any of the structure’s stored properties are file
> private, the initializer is file private. Otherwise, the initializer
> has an access level of internal.

Just use a custom initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use default member wise `initialiser` for assigning `struct's` property with `private` access level modifier.If you need to assign your private property using `initializer`, you have to write your own OR give private member initiate value resolves it

Comment: I’m not trying to assign to the private property. Or do you mean my default value? Does that negate the whole member wise initialiser?

Comment: in initialiser ... give it defaut value

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
struct Obligation {
    var date: Date
    private var blank: Bool
    
    init(date: Date = Date(), blank: Bool = false) {
       self.date = date
       self.blank = black
    }
}
    
let snapshotEntry = Obligation(date: Date())
```